# Geolocation APIs for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation

I am trying to show map for a location from my rails app.I tried checking YM4R/GM and GeoKit combination but not sure if there is something better for rails 3.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear if anyone else has a good option for Rails 3 (or even Rails 2.3+) apart from YM4R/GM or YM4R/Mapstraction. Currently use this gem for a couple of sites but I'm not sure if it's still being maintained.
Noticed that the APIs referenced by the YM4R/Mapstraction are hardcoded in and the APIs referenced for Bing and Google are pretty old now.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Ruby GeoCoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/). It allows street address lookup, IP address lookup 
and geographic coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [RGeo](http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/archives/28). It looks nice, but I don't have any experience with it.